# « Le matin » vs « au matin »

Tags: indications-de-temps, niveau-de-langue

J'aimerais savoir s'il existe une expression d'un plus haut registre de langue parmi « au matin » et « le matin ». L'une d'elle est-elle désuète ?

Par exemple :

- *Il s'est produit un incident le 28 au matin.*
- *Il s'est produit un incident le matin du 28.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Les deux sont correctes, usuelles, du même registre ; certains peuvent penser que la première est légèrement plus soutenue, plus littéraire, la seconde employée plus facilement à l'oral :

Les deux construction sont possibles elles inversent la date et la période du jour ; on peut aussi préciser l'heure de l’événement :

> - "il s'est produit un incident le 28 [ *à* 8 heures du { de *le* } matin --> ] / [ au matin]."
> - "il s'est produit un incident le matin du 28 [ à 8 heures ]."

Comment: J'ai l'impression que `le 28 au matin` insiste sur le fait que l’événement à eu lieu tôt dans la journée. Alors que `le matin du 28` n'insiste pas, le fait que ce se soit passé le matin n'a pas beaucoup d'importance. Peut-être est-ce un effet de bord sur le fait que `au matin` est légèrement plus rare, et que cela génère une effet de mise en avant de l'expression... ?

Comment: @Random Votre lecture semble être: "Cela s'est passé quand ?" - "Le 28 / Le matin" - "Plus précisément ?" - "Au matin / le 28" ; on peut lire aussi "Quand a eu l'incident ?" - "Le 28 / Le matin"... ici tout dépend de la signification de l'incident, répondre "Le 27 / Le soir" pourrait indiquer un autre incident avec des conséquences différentes.

Comment: Pardon mais j'ai du mal à suivre la signification des "/" ici ?

Comment: @ Random On répond à chaque interrogation, soit avec la partie à gauche à chaque question en utilisant le modèle de la première ligne jaune de la question, soit avec celle de droite avec la seconde ligne jaune. Cela s'est passé quand ?" - "Le 28 / ____" - "Plus précisément ?" - "Au matin / ____ " ;

Answer (score -1):

"Au matin" est une expression typiquement picarde ou chti ! 
Je l'entends énormément dans la région et dit avec l'accent.

Comment: "Au matin" n'est pas typiquement picard ou chti. C'est très usuel dans la France entière.