# Aux / les jours de pluie

Tags: prépositions

Bonjour,

*L'escargot* de Paul Starosta :

> **Aux** jours de pluie, les repas durent pendant des heures. Équipé de 4
> tentacules et de 2 yeux, l'escargot repère ce qui est bon à manger.

Quelle est la différence entre "**aux** jours de pluie" et "**les** jours de pluie" ? Est-ce que le premier tour est plus littéraire ?

Ajout : j'ai trouvé une explication ici, [« Le matin » vs « au matin »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/13923/le-matin-vs-au-matin) ; vraisemblablement, il s'agit de la même logique, donc il semble que "**aux** jours de pluie" soit plus littéraire que
"**les** jours de pluie".

Answer (score 1):

« Au »  et « les » confèrent au nom qui les suit un contexte d'utilisation qui dépend de la nature du nom et du contexte général.

« Le » confère l'idée de répétition régulière, mais seulement selon le contexte. « Au » confère l'idée de changement de situation, de progression vers une situation, mais pas immanquablement non plus, le contexte étant déterminant.

- **Le** matin, il dort, toujours très tard, et récupère après ses longues soirées passées à boire de l'alcool.
- Elle fait ses courses **le** matin, **l**'après-midi elle travaille à sa peinture.
- Des bléssés avaient été amenés à l'hôpital depuis minuit, et il semblait qu'il en arrivait toujours plus ; **au** matin, il n'y avait déjà plus de lit et un certain nombre d'entre eux avaient pu être installés à même le sol sur des couvertures.
- Ils savaient qu'un long hiver les attendait mais qu'**aux** beaux jours la vie reprendrait comme avant.
- Elle avait finalement décidé : elle ferait son ravaudage le soir-même et **au** matin elle irait ramasser du bois mort.

Cette idée de progression ou de changement n'est pas nécessairement retenue par un auteur, il a le choix, comme le montre l'extrait suivant de  *La chèvre de Monsieur Seguin* d'Alphonse Daudet.

- Un moment, en se rappelant l'histoire de la vieille Renaude, qui s'était battue toute la nuit pour être mangée **le** matin, elle se dit qu'il vaudrait peut-être mieux se laisser manger tout de suite ; (*Il n'y a évidemment pas d'idée de répétition habituelle dans le présent usage de « le ».*)

Il aurait pu utiliser « au ».

- Un moment, en se rappelant l'histoire de la vieille Renaude, qui s'était battue toute la nuit pour être mangée **au** matin, elle se dit qu'il vaudrait peut-être mieux se laisser manger tout de suite ;

En ce qui concerne la phrase de Starosta, l s'agit en fait de la même logique sur le plan de l'habitude. Il aurait mieux marqué la répétition habituelle en utilisant « les », mais il n'a pas choisi de le faire (même si l'idée d'action habituelle est encore reconnaissable), et « aux » dans ce cas ne dénote pas du tout une idée de progression.

- **Les** jours de pluie, les repas durent pendant des heures. Équipé de 4 tentacules et de 2 yeux, l'escargot repère ce qui est bon à manger.

Quel usage est plus littéraire ? C'est bien difficile à déterminer ; s'il y en a un qui le soit plus que l'autre, ce ne peut pas être d'une façon très caractéristique. Néanmoins, il existe une différence d'usage difficile à appréhender, ce qui est discuté dans la suite.

Dans la langue parlé ou littéraire il n'est pas possible de remplacer « aux » par « les » dans la phrase suivante.

- Aux moments difficiles, les coéquipiers passent plus de temps à se concerter.
- <s>Les moments difficiles, les coéquipiers …</s>

Le pourquoi semble être que le référent n'est pas le *cadre* d'une action répétée habituellement mais *l'action elle-même* représentée métonymiquement ; donné ce contexte « **dans les** », « **pour les** » et d'autres locutions peuvent être préférées.

- Aux cas difficiles, il y a toujours deux docteurs qui vont discuter la décision finale.
- <s>Les cas difficiles, il y a toujours …</s>
- Dans/pour les cas difficiles il y a …
- Aux années exceptionnelles, les rapports peuvent être améliorés jusqu'au point de doubler. (*« année » en tant que « récolte » ; « les » ne va pas.*)
- Les années froides, la germination est moins abondante. (*au cours des années ; « aux » est un remplacement possible.*)
- Aux années froides, la germination est moins abondante.

Comment: Je vous remercie pour votre réponse. // À propos des trois dernières phrases, _**Aux** années exceptionnelles_, _**Les** années..._ est impossible pace que cette phrase n'a pas l'idée de répétition ? Car _**Les** années froides_ est correct.

Comment: @Oreste Non, ce n'est pas parce « les » ne communiquerait pas une idée de répétition, mais encore une fois parce  « une année » n'est pas le cadre de l'action, c'est au lieu de cela quasiment l'action elle-même du fait que « année », métonymiquement, veut dire « récolte ». Dans le cas de « années froides », la germination (action) se fait dans le cadre d'une année froide, donc « les » convient,  selon le même principe.  Je n'ai malheureusement pas de références pour ces usages, et si vous gardez des notes ce serait une bonne idée d'ajouter que les références manquent.

Comment: _parce « une année » n'est pas le cadre de l'action, c'est au lieu de cela quasiment l'action elle-même du fait que « année », métonymiquement, veut dire « récolte »_ --- Je ne comprends toujours pas, mais ce n'est pas grave. À mon avis, _Aux années exceptionnelles_ et _Aux années froides_ sont les cadres d'une action, tous les deux. // _si vous gardez des notes_ --- Je ne comprends pas, quelles notes ?

Comment: _ne communiquerait pas une idée de répétition_ --- Vous employez le conditionnel pour introduire l'idée de hypothèse ?